# Splashscreen and main activity configuration

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I have an application starting at a splash screen loading contact list, then when finished, it starts the main activity ; what could be the best way to configure these two in manifest , for intent filters action ans category ?

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:noHistory="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question...I would configure them as usual and set the `LAUNCHER` `intent-filter` to your `SplashScreenActivity`:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.SplashScreenActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And after loading your `contactList` you would start you MainActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
//Note your contactList must be Parcelable
intent.putExtra("CONTACT_LIST",contactList);
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: this is what i am doing for splash screen , but i'm confused about main activity (question edited)